# How to output css files as .css files instead of inline <style> in nuxt.js?

Tags: css, vuejs2, nuxt.js

How can I convert inline-CSS to CSS-files in nuxt.js? I have both scoped styles and global scss file in my app.
I have already tried below code but no luck.

```
build: {
    optimization: {
      splitChunks: {
        chunks: 'all',
        automaticNameDelimiter: '.',
        name: 'rameez',
        cacheGroups: {}
      }
    },
    optimizeCSS:true
  }
```

here you can see all the CSS including my global.scss is shown as an inline style.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are looking for [extractCss](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build#extractcss) property i think

```
build:{
    extractCSS: true
}
```

Comment: I was already using `extractCSS: true` but was checking the output in dev mode.. that made me confuse, I think it extracts CSS in prod mode by default. anyway thanks.

Comment: @RameezRami yes, it wont work on dev. But no, on prod it default to false too, u need to set it yourself

Comment: yes that's why I said I was already using extractCSS: true :)